# Browserifing Loopback's client

Tags: browserify, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to get this working: [Running LoopBack in the browser](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Running+LoopBack+in+the+browser)

Whilst API works great, attempt to browserify the copy of file 'browser-app.js' throw an error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'loopback-boot#instructions' from 'APP_DIR/node_modules/loopback-boot'

**Update**

The code:

**client/js/app.js**

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();
boot(app);
```

**Browserifing**:

```
browserify client/js/app.js -o client/js/bundle.js
Error: Cannot find module 'loopback-boot#instructions' from 'APP_DIR/node_modules/loopback-boot'
    at /opt/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /opt/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)
```

Comment: I'd suggest showing the code you are using directly in the question, even if it's identical to docs. the strongloop docs seem to change often (and it would confirm that you're doing the same as in the docs)

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. I've added the code and response of browserify to the question.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of loopback-boot? seems it was updated 22 hours ago, in particular the part that's failing for you.

Comment: mine is 2.6.5 and `npm update` does nothing. Can OS affect that?

Comment: Is this related to your problem? seems somewhat similar. https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-boot/issues/53

Comment: It is related but I did not use --full-paths option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73455/discussion-between-leitasat-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at this example: https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-example-isomorphic

The gulp task **build:lb-client** does the magic:

```
gulp.task('build:lb-client', ['clean'], function(done) {
  var b = browserify({basedir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/loopback')});
  b.require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/loopback/index.js'),
    {expose: 'lbclient'});
  try {
    boot.compileToBrowserify({appRootDir: path.resolve(__dirname,
      'client/loopback')}, b);
  } catch(e) {
    throw e;
  }

  var target = fs.createWriteStream('client/public/js/bundle.js');
  target
    .on('error', done)
    .on('close', done);
  b.bundle().pipe(target);
});
```

Run it with `gulp build:lb-client` and you'll find the file `bundle.js` inside the directory `client/public/js/`, the file is ready to be included in a web page.